# Background color property in css for IE8 not working as expected unlike other browsers

Tags: css

I have applied two different styles for two different text buttons.

```
.BC { 
background-color : DC143C;
color: white;
font-size: 12px;
display: block;
height: 21px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bolder;
}

.DE { 
background-color : black;
color: white;
font-size: 12px;
display: block;
height: 21px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bolder;
}
```

The look and feel of the buttons are great in Mozilla,chrome,Opera and Safari browser with the expected colour changes(ie the button appers with default length and the text is wrapped inside it).But in IE8 and IE9 the color is applied only upto the text what I have mentioned and adjusts itself with the buttton structure.

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Hey used to `#` before in color

as like this

```
background-color : #DC143C;
```

and replace this one

```
.BC{background-color : #DC143C;}
```